# How do you get all ENV variables from Heroku (Including internal variables)

Tags: shell, heroku, environment-variables, heroku-cli

How do I get `HEROKU` specific `ENV` variables? (Such as `$HEROKU_API_KEY_ENC`)

I'm writing a buildpack to perform some operations on app deploys (not dyno restart, just deploy) but I need to know which variables are available at that point.

I know I have access to my own environment variables and `HEROKU runtime dyno metadata` but I'd like to see what else is there, such as which git user is making the deploy, or whether there's a variable to determine it is a deploy or a restart etc.

I appreciate your help.

P.S I already tried `deployhooks` and it doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

The linux `printenv` command will display every available environment variable.

Answer (score 2):

How about this

```
heroku config --app your_app_id | grep "your_variable"
```